# Apollo server, GraphQL and Sequelize - how to put raw data into a GraphQL Schema Response

Tags: stored-procedures, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

After scouring the internet for a specific example, I am throwing in the towel and asking for some help.

I am using Apollo server, GraphQL and Sequelize, and I am calling stored procedure that returns a record set created from two different tables. I am getting the data back, but I cannot figure out how to put the result into a GraphQL schema response.

Here is the code in my resolver:

```
async functionName(_, {input}, {user = null}) {
    if (!user) {
        throw new AuthenticationError('You must login to use this function');
    }
    const {record_id} = input;
    const result = await DBService.query(
        'Call sp_JoinTwoTables_Select(:id)',
        {
            model: FooModel,
            mapToModel: true,
            raw: true,
            replacements: {id: record_id},
            type: QueryTypes.SELECT
        }
    );
    console.log('functionName.result');
    console.log(result); // Getting results
    return result;
}
```

Here is the code in my schema:

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server-express');

module.exports = gql`
    type Foo {
        id: Int!
        foo_name: String!
        date_created: String!
        date_modified: String!
    }

    extend type Mutation {
        functionName(input: fooInput!): fooResponse!
    }

    input fooInput {
        id: Int!
    }

    type fooResponse {
        tree: [fooSchemaForBothTables!]
    }
    type fooSchemaForBothTables {
        id: Int!
        foo_name: String!
        column_from_second_table: Int!
    }
`;
```

Since there is no table in the database, I created a simple object. When that failed I tried a sequelized model object, but that also is failing. Here is this code:

```
module.exports = {FooModel: {
    id: 0,
    fooName: '',
    column_from_second_table: 0
}};
```

The output I am getting is (not a 2d array as I thought):

```
Executing (default): Call sp_CommunityHierarchy_Select(9)
selectHierarchyTree.result
[
  {
    '0': {
      community_id: 1,
      community_name: 'Cars',
      level_from_apex: null,
      parent_id: null
    },
    '1': {
      community_id: 8,
      community_name: 'Chevy',
      level_from_apex: 2,
      parent_id: 1
    },
    '2': {
      community_id: 9,
      community_name: 'Suburban',
      level_from_apex: 3,
      parent_id: 8
    },
    meta: [ [ColumnDef], [ColumnDef], [ColumnDef], [ColumnDef] ]
  },
  { affectedRows: 6, insertId: 0, warningStatus: 0 }
]
```

Comment: what (shape) is returned from DB? ... how (looking at grqphql types) [do you think] the response (shape) should look like?

Comment: The shape is a basic record set, 2 dimensional array, where each record matches the schema fooSchemaForBothTables in the example I gave.

Comment: `console.log(result)` ?

Comment: I added the output of the result into my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'raw' DB result:

- is an array;
- 1st element is an object with records/items encoded as index-named properties;

Your required mutation (why not a query type!?) response should `tree: [fooSchemaForBothTables!]` - object with `tree` named property (really required additional nesting level?) with an array of `fooSchemaForBothTables`-shaped objects as values:

```
{
  tree: [
    {
      id: 1,
      foo_name: 'Cars`,
      column_from_second_table: 'whatever`,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      foo_name: 'Chevy`,
      column_from_second_table: 'whatever`,
    }
  ]
}
```

**Your job is to convert DB response into the required mutation result shape.**

**Hint:** You can hardcode this DB result (some input const) in a side project (codesandbox) and write some conversion fn. When ready use it in this resolver.

You can also search for some more reliable **sequelize** (leave graphql alone for a moment) tutorials with 'more working' model mapping.

### Next step?

If it is a tree then why not return this as a tree structure - nested nodes/types?

Comment: Going to work through your comments. Most of my answers to your questions as to why I am doing things this way is because I haven't seen a good example yet, or one that I understand, so I am trying different things out. They are probably the long way to doing something easy. Thank you for your help I will update this once I have it working.

Comment: What I found worked for me. It may not work for other scenarios. My stored proc had some overhead, or could, so when it runs it would store the results into a flattened "cache" table. What I did was create a sequelize model for the cache table and when I got the results and used the sequelize model build() to stuff each record into that and push that into an array, and that was the output. Worked out well. If anyone needs more help with this, just leave a comment and i will try to explain it better.